# Example $f_n = \mathbf{1}_{[n,\infty)}$ in Fatou's Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

In the class, my professor gave the following example:

Let $f_n = \mathbf{1}_{[n,\infty)}$, then we have

$$\int_X \lim\inf f_n = 0, \text{ since } \lim\inf f_n = 0,$$ 
and 
$$\lim\inf \int_X f_n = \infty, \text{ since } \int f_n = \infty, \forall n.$$

I can understand "$\int f_n = \infty, \forall n$". But even so, what is the key reason that $$\int_X \lim\inf f_n = 0 \, \text{ but } \, \lim\inf \int_X f_n = \infty$$

To me for the second case, when $n\rightarrow \infty$, it should be $0$. I am confused on this point.

Comment: Fatou's lemma is an **inequality**.

Comment: $\liminf \infty=\infty$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, so I think this example shows $<$ not just $\leq$.

Comment: A less contentious example is $f_n = 1_{[n,n+1)}$. Then $\liminf_n f_n = 0$ and $\int f_n = 1$, so $0 = \int \liminf_n f_n \le \liminf_n \int f_n =1 $.

Comment: For all $n$, $\int_X f_n =  \infty$.

Comment: About "this example shows $<$ not just $\leq$": In this example, you have $<$; in other examples, you have $=$. Theorems have to apply to all cases (as long as the hypotheses are satisfied). So this theorem says $\leq$, which applies to all the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are considering the sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ where the $n^{th}$ function of the sequence is given by $$f_n(x):=\begin{cases}0 & \text{if } x\in (-\infty,n)  \\ 1 & \text{otherwise} .\end{cases}$$

We have the pointwise limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)=0$, and so $\int \lim f_n =0$. But for each $n  \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $\int f_n=\infty$, and so $\lim \int f_n=\infty$ (limit of a constant sequence).

The difference comes from what limit we are evaluating. On one hand we have the integral of a pointwise limit function, where the pointwise limit happens to be constantly $0$. And on the other hand we have the limit of a constant sequence of extended real numbers.